# [AWS][EKS][Fargate] x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: x509, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm building an AWS EKS cluster with Fargate managed nodes and everything is fine till I want to pull a docker image from a remote on-premise docker registry hosted on Harbor. CA is fully private on on-premise and I thought that this could be an issue.

As a workaround, I tried to create an Apache proxy with SSL key and cert generated by AWS PCA **(from another account!)**. Later customized docker pull endpoint call to move (pull) through this proxy.
I tested this setup from the proxy instance as well as another bastion host instance and images are pulling correctly with Harbor authentication (not from EKS).

I checked and CA created in AWS PCA is not expired (2022 date expiration).

From inside AWS EKS, this pull doesn't work correctly. I'm including error messages:

```html
    Events:
  Type     Reason           Age   From               Message
  ----     ------           ----  ----               -------
  Warning  LoggingDisabled  78s   fargate-scheduler  Disabled logging because aws-logging configmap was not found. configmap "aws-logging" not found
  Normal   Scheduled        5s    fargate-scheduler  Successfully assigned <name-of-deployment-here> to fargate-ip-10-155-250-49.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling          2s    kubelet            Pulling image "<image_name_here>"
  Warning  Failed           2s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "<apache-proxy-address>/<docker-repository-address>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<apache-proxy-address>/<docker-repository-address>": failed to resolve reference "<apache-proxy-address>/<docker-repository-address>: failed to do request: Head https://<apache-proxy-address>/<****>/<docker-repository-address>: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed           2s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff          1s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "<apache-proxy-address>/<docker-repository-address>"
  Warning  Failed           1s    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Error is caused by:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem at the moment. We have to wait for AWS to implement private certificate support in EKS from ACM Private CA. Currently, certificates accepted by the EKS service have to be signed by some public CA.